# OpenSSH_7.4 Encryption Config

Tags: implementation

I have noticed that recent versions of OpenSSH allows the reporting of capabilities by using ssh -Q .

The last time I really looked at my SSH setup was a couple of years ago (stribika) -- but I have been spurred on to revisit this topic, and changes of abilities and opinions since then.

Working through the possible options, three 'queries' and subsequent ssh and sshd configuration options appear simple and straightforward:

```
* ssh -Q cipher & ssh -Q cipher-auth
  --> Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,...
* ssh -Q mac
  --> MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,...
* ssh -Q kex
  --> KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,...
```

However, the rest has me confused -- partly that some of these settings are new, and I'm not sure I understand what the settings actually do...

ssh -Q key / key-cert / key-plain each give distinct lists.

HostKeyAlgorithms, HostbasedKeyTypes & PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes are the three remaining configuration options.

Can someone please explain these three settings, why they are useful, and why I might find it useful to have different settings for the 3 of them (because it appears to me at first glance that they should all be set to the same values)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is about using crypto in a particular program, not how crypto itself works, which is probably why it was downvoted, and based on history is likely to be closed.

`-Q key` should be (exactly) the union of `key-plain` and `key-cert`. OpenSSH's idiosyncratic certs have been there a *long* time, over which they have evolved a little, but
* ecdsa-sha2-nistp{256,384,521}[-cert-\$v] is new since IIRC 6.0
* ssh-ed25519[-cert-\$v] is new since 6.5, and
* ssh-dss[-cert-\$v] was removed from default since 7.0.

The ssh_config (and sshd_config) options are explained on their man pages, but since an unprecedented flaw in your video card apparently prevents it from displaying text from those specific pages, I have copied and joined the important parts for you, although I can't easily preserve the exact formatting.

> #### HostbasedKeyTypes
>
> [client] Specifies the key types that will be used for hostbased authentication as a comma-separated pattern list. Alternately if the specified value begins with a ‘+’ character, then the specified key types will be appended to the default set instead of replacing them. If the specified value begins with a ‘-’ character, then the specified key types (including wildcards) will be removed from the default set instead of replacing them. The default for this option is: [snipped]
>
> #### HostbasedAcceptedKeyTypes
>
> [server] Specifies the key types that will be accepted for hostbased authentication as a comma-separated pattern list. [same rules for + and -, and default]

'Hostbased' authentication is a combination of machine-wide pubkey plus an rhosts-style list of names. It is defaulted to off and rarely used because host-name resolution usually isn't secure, and trusting *all* users on another host is often undesired.

> #### HostKeyAlgorithms
>
> [client] Specifies the host key algorithms that the client wants to use in order of preference. [same rules for + and -, and default except:] If hostkeys are known for the destination host then this default is modified to prefer their algorithms.
>   [server] Specifies the host key algorithms that the server offers. [same default]

These are the (pubkey) algorithms that will be used to authenticate the server (host), and if changed from the default should match whatever key types your server(s) actually have. You can either change the enabled algorithms to match the actual host keys, or create new host keys to match the enabled algorithms. In practice most servers automatically generate one key of each supported type counting all ecdsa as one type since they use the same filename.
(The server code actually handles the + and - rules as well, but apparently this didn't get to the manpage.)

> #### PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
>
> [client] Specifies the key types that will be used for public key authentication as a comma-separated pattern list. [same rules for + and -, and default]
>   [server] Specifies the key types that will be accepted for public key authentication as a comma-separated pattern list. [same rules for + and -, and default]

These are the pubkey algorithms that the client will use to try to authenticate to the server (host). Again if changed from default they should match the key type(s) your client(s) have. Since client keys are only generated manually, this depends on the choices made by the people who do or did the generation.

PS: although your title says encryption, none of these involves or is related to encryption.